# Empty response on specific hashtag from Instagram API

Tags: instagram, hashtag, instagram-api

I'm trying to get photos using [instafeedjs](http://instafeedjs.com)

It works with some hashtags, like "starbucks", but doesn't show any result for special hashtag "starbuckssurpriseme".

There are 97 photos under "#starbuckssurpriseme" that can be viewed in Instagram app.

Here is the sample code:

```js
    var feed = new Instafeed({
      get: 'tagged',
      tagName: 'starbucks',
      clientId: '86e61cc3046a4034aaeb317494aea040'
    });
    feed.run();
```

```css
#instafeed a {
  padding: 5px 5px 1px 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
}
#instafeed .likes {
  background: rgba(222, 89, 135, 0.8);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  color: #ffffff;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 100ms ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 100ms ease;
  -o-transition: opacity 100ms ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 100ms ease;
  transition: opacity 100ms ease;
}
#instafeed a:hover .likes {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://f.cl.ly/items/3o2z3b1R3G250G1t0w2L/instafeed.min.js"></script>
<div id="instafeed"></div>
hello
```

Do you know what can cause empty response from Instagram API?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all 97 photos on #starbuckssurpriseme are from a private profile.

You can see these photos because your clientId probably follows the private profile. With my Instagram i can see the counter at 97, but i can't see any photo.

This means that your clientId should be following the private profile.

Comment: @niksen, accept the answer so other people can see that as the correct one.